Charge renormalization Only Arise From Radiative Correction to the Photon Propagator
In Weinberg's QFT V1 section 10.4, he say that there is only radiative corrections to the photon propagator contributing to the charge renormalization, and other radiative corrections to the propagators and electro-magnetic vertices of the charged particles would cancell with each others.
Then he tries to prove the statement via general Ward identity,
$$(l-k)_{\mu}\Gamma^{\mu}(k,l) = i(S'^{-1}(k) - S'^{-1}(l))\tag{10.4.25}$$
He claim that a fermion on the mass shell interacts with an electro-magnetic field with $0$ momentum transfer would be the case when we set out to measure the fermion's electric charge.
$$\bar{u}'_{k}\Gamma^{\mu}(k,k)u_{k} = \bar{u}'_{k}\gamma^{\mu}u_{k}\tag{10.4.28}$$
I'm confused with the statement that the interaction with an EM field with $0$ momentum transfer of the EM field, why this would be the case that we measure the electric charge?
It seems to me that eq(10.4.19) already implies how to measure the electric charge, why we need additional $0$ momentum transfer situation?
